# ¿Cómo cambiar múltiples columnas numericas a factor?

Tags: r

Quiero cambiar valores numericos de un dataframe por factores, pero de todas las columnas de mi dataframe, logré hacerlo utilizando el comando factor y creando un objeto nuevo, pero el codigo quedó algo grande y me gustaría simplificarlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
confianza2$p10_1 <- factor(confianza2$p10_1,
                                  levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                                  labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_2 <- factor(confianza2$p10_2,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_3 <- factor(confianza2$p10_3,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_4 <- factor(confianza2$p10_4,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_5 <- factor(confianza2$p10_5,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_6 <- factor(confianza2$p10_6,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10"))
confianza2$p10_7 <- factor(confianza2$p10_7,
                           levels = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                           labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin son todas las columnas, menos la primera, las que buscas cambiar puedes hacerlo así:

```
as.data.frame(
  sapply(confianza[, -1], 
         factor, 
         levels = 1:10, 
         labels = c("Valor 1", "Valor 2", "Valor 3", "Valor 4", "Valor 5", "Valor 6", 
                    "Valor 7", "Valor 8", "Valor 9", "Valor 10")
         )
  ) -> confianza[, -1]
```

Básicamente aplicas `factor` sobre cada columna de `confianza`, el retorno será una matriz, por lo que convertimos en un `data.frame`

Comment: Y si quisiera que la columna 1 no se modificara? porque son los numeros de folio y también los reconocería

Comment: Revisa mi última edición.

Comment: muchas gracias!